# Why am I getting the following error in vue.js 3; "external_commonjs_vue_commonjs2_vue_root_Vue_default.a is undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, vuejs3, vue-component

I installed a file upload component called `vue-file-agent`, and I got the error `"external_commonjs_vue_commonjs2_vue_root_Vue_default.a is undefined"` in my console.

**The Code:**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import VueFileAgent from 'vue-file-agent';
import 'vue-file-agent/dist/vue-file-agent.css';

createApp(App).use(VueFileAgent).mount('#app')
```